# Is it possible to isolate C function from changes to its parameter type?

Tags: c

I would like to know if it is possible to code any function `f` that takes a structure S as a parameter while, in case we want to make drastic change to `struct S`, we can do it without touching a single hair of `f` ?

Ok, i'll share here what blows and finally your comments will help me to understand things better:
They need a kind of contract, for example :

R1) each time `f` needs something from `struct S` then `f` access to it through a function that `struct S` promise to keep accessible.

Comment: What's wrong? It has no sensible title. It is too broad. Short answer: yes. Longer answer: it depends what the function does with/to S.

Comment: Ok, i will precise it but i am a quasi beginner.

Comment: In comment i will go on with my own vocabulary :
I think the answer is yes if ``struct S`` and ``f`` have made a kind of contract.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with higher order functions (function pointers) and void pointers.

Consider this sorting code:

```
typedef struct node{
  void* item;
  struct node* next;
} Node;

/* Bubble sort the given linked list */
void bubbleSort(Node *start, bool greaterThan(void* a, void* b)) 
{ 
    int swapped, i; 
    Node *ptr1; 
    Node *lptr = NULL; 

    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (start == NULL) 
        return; 

    do
    { 
        swapped = 0; 
        ptr1 = start; 

        while (ptr1->next != lptr) 
        { 
            if (greaterThan(ptr1->item, ptr1->next->item))
            { 
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next); 
                swapped = 1; 
            } 
            ptr1 = ptr1->next; 
        } 
        lptr = ptr1; 
    } 
    while (swapped); 
} 


/* function to swap data of two nodes a and b*/
void swap(Node *a, Node *b) 
{ 
    void* temp = a->item; 
    a->item = b->item; 
    b->item = temp; 
}
```

By making the `item` in the node for the linked list a void pointer, it makes it possible to store an instance of *any struct* in the node.

The `greaterThan` function allows the `bubbleSort` function to work properly with any struct.  For example, given the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
   int  book_id;
   char title[50];
   char author[50];
   char subject[100];
   char ISBN[13];
} Book;
```

I can compare the two books for sorting purposes:

```
bool bookGreaterThan(void* left, void* right)
{
  Book* a = (Book*)left;
  Book* b = (Book*)right;

  return strcmp(a->title, b->title) > 0;
}
```

And I can tell my bubbleSort function how to sort Books like this:

```
bubbleSort(firstNodeInMyBookList, bookGreaterThan);
```

[Complete, working example here](https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/Sorting-with-Comparator-Function-in-C)